# Cells are not displayed in MVVM APP (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am writing an application to display news from the server. Created a StartController class that only displays data from the ViewModel. There are no warnings in the project, but at startup, a blank screen.

```
final class StartController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Private properties
    
    private var viewModel: ViewModel?
    private let identifier = "tapeCell"
    private let tableView = CustomTableView(frame: .zero)
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
        setUpConstraints()
        reloadViewModel()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private functions
    
    private func reloadViewModel() {
        viewModel?.configData { [weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setUpView() {
        view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
}

// MARK: - Delegate

extension StartController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
}

// MARK: - DataSource

extension StartController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        viewModel?.numberOfRowsInSection() ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        let VM = self.viewModel?.articleAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        
        content.text = VM?.title
        content.secondaryText = VM?.author
        cell.contentConfiguration = content
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

All the logic takes place inside the ViewModel, downloading data from the network and transferring it to the StartController. But apparently, no data is being transmitted.

```
final class ViewModel {
    
    // MARK: - Private properties
    
    private let service = TapeService()
    private var data: [Articles] = []
    
    // MARK: - Functions
    
    func configData(completion: @escaping() -> ()) {
        service.tapeAdd { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let articles):
                self?.data = articles
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfRowsInSection() -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func articleAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> ArticleViewModel {
        let article = self.data[index]
        return ArticleViewModel(article)
    }
}

// MARK: - ArticleViewModel

final class ArticleViewModel {
    private let article: Articles
    
    init(_ article: Articles) {
        self.article = article
    }
    
    var title: String {
        return self.article.title ?? " "
    }
    
    var author: String {
        return self.article.author ?? " "
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful if you could tell me what my mistake is and what needs to be done to display the data. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you assign the viewModel? Also, are you assigning the constraints correctly? Show that code

Comment: before view.addSubview(tableView) give frame to tableview.frame = view.frame

Comment: They don't need to do that if they are adding constraints

Comment: I don't designate ViewModel anywhere else, except for the StartController file

Comment: As Zeeshan Ahmad II already said, the frame of your tableView is zero.

Comment: In configData I do not see that you call the completion (=reloadData)

Comment: I added reloadData, but this not helped me:                                                          case .success(let articles):
                self?.data = articles
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.startController.tableView.reloadData()
                }